# jQuery hotkeys plugin uses bind

Tags: jquery, event-handling, hotkeys, jquery-hotkeys

I'm using the [jQuery hotkeys plugin](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys), written by John Resig (Mr jQuery). It uses `bind`, however, and `bind` is now replaced by `on` as noted in [the official jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

The standard code is:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', 'alt+a', function(evt){...});
```

I tried changing `bind` to `on`, but it didn't work. Is there a workaround, or does it not matter?

I'm also wondering whether attaching the handler to the document is always going to be the best way.

Comment: try $(document).on('keyup', null, 'alt+a', function(){}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`on` take an extra DOM arg, http://api.jquery.com/on/, so write `null`.

try

```
$(document).on('keyup', null, 'alt+a', function(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin redeclares the use of the `.bind` and `.unbind` methods of jQuery as seen in these lines

```
jQuery.fn.bind = function(){
jQuery.fn.unbind = function(){
```

We can simply do

```
jQuery.fn.on = function(){
jQuery.fn.off = function(){
```

This also needs to be changed -

```
jQuery.fn.__bind__ = jQuery.fn.bind;
jQuery.fn.__unbind__ = jQuery.fn.unbind;
```

To

```
jQuery.fn.__bind__ = jQuery.fn.on;
jQuery.fn.__unbind__ = jQuery.fn.off;
```

It's reused a couple times, so replace any occurence of `bind` **note** -- Do not replace `__bind`, just `bind` occurences with on, and `unbind` occurences with off.

[Or just use the code in my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzJGe/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although my copy of the plugin didn't make any reference to either `bind` or `on` except in the implementation lines. I've gone with Jonathan's answer.